# EntityFramework in .net6 "no entity type mapped to the table"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I've upgraded my code from .net3.1 to .net6 and now when I try to rebuild my database from scratch I'm getting this error:

[image: error]

But as you can see in the same image, there is an entity configured to use that table!

the code in the migration that is failing is just the insertion of some data:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                schema: "dbo",
                table: "PlannerGroup",
                columns: new[] { "PlannerGroupId", "PlannerGroupName", "Position" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 30, "Bread", 31 },
                    { 31, "Drinks", 32 }
                });
        }
```

How do I fix this error?

How can I specify the type or the column types in the operation?

Comment: And how are you entity type configurations are applied?

Comment: in my ModelContext on the OnModelCreating method I have this: modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PlannerGroupConfiguration());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my scenario, the solution was to delete the "schema: "dbo", argument.
Having just this works:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "PlannerGroup",
                columns: new[] { "PlannerGroupId", "PlannerGroupName", "Position" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 30, "Bread", 31 },
                    { 31, "Drinks", 32 }
                });
        }
```

I suppose .net6 doesn't like redundant arguments very much...

Answer (score 3):

I explicitly name the types for the columns using columnTypes:

```
migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            table: "MyTable"
            columnTypes: new string[] { "bigint", "string", "string", "bit" },
            columns: new[] { "pkMyTableId", "myTableClientName", "myTableBodyText", "isExpired" },
            values: new object[] { 1L, "Bob", "Welcome to the town", false });
```

Comment: This also worked for me for the above error, but I am not sure what should be the type of `datetimeoffset` column. I tried `datetime` as column type and it worked but I wonder if that would be the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered several issues that were causing this exception, when upgrading from dotnet 3.1 to 6.0 and using `dotnet ef migrations script` to generate SQL migrations files on existing old migrations.

1. the missing `columnTypes` on migrationBuilder.InsertData. For some reason the new EF version always expect to have.
2. The missing `schema:` prop in some  migrationBuilder.UpdateData blocks. Now it is always required.
3. And the most annoying one: having `migrationBuilder.UpdateData / AlterColumn` blocks for tables that were then deleted/renamed with a later migration.

The 3d one is really baffling, because it was working ok in dotnet 3.1, unless you had a custom `migrationBuilder.Sql` statement that did not wrap the sql in EXEC''. It seems Microsoft fixed the need to wrap everything in EXEC but introduced another issue... Fortunatelly it is an easy fix, but you need to go through all old migrations and delete the Update/Alter statements for deleted or renamed tables (and possibly columns)

Comment: This  doesn't answer the question. The part that somewhat answers the question is already covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77025419/861716).

Answer (score -1):

I delete the database schema and it works.